# How does the Windows Task Manager compute the link speed for each network adapter?

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, task-manager, internet-speed

The Windows Task Manager shows the link speed for each network adapter?

[image]

[image]

Sometimes the link speed oscillates (between 130 and 144 Mbps in the example
below, where the network adapter is a USB WiFi Adapter ([TP-Link Archer T3U Plus](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08D72GSMS)), even though I am not moving my computer):

[image]

How does the Windows Task Manager compute the link speed for each network adapter?

Comment: @FrankThomas interesting, thanks, do you know what could explain the oscillation?

Comment: so I deleted my comment because it is clearly not entirely true for wireless. I'm no expert on modern wifi, but I am guessing that its based on frequencies and power, that the system controls for optimal performance. power matters for wireless in a way it doesn't for wired.

Comment: Potential duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1226681/why-is-my-wi-fi-router-showing-link-speed-of-72-mbps and more at https://superuser.com/search?q=wireless+link+speed

Comment: Just because you are not moving does not mean that the local electromagnetic conditions are the same from second to second. Your computer will be cycling up and down in terms of clock speed, people will be turning microwaves on and off and others will also be using the same spectrum for their own WiFi and Bluetooth devices. The router and WiFi receiver will be adjusting signalling rates to find the best and will ramp up to a higher rate and then backing off if performance falls.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, yes just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Windows does not calculate anything really. The wifi protocol(s) have a feature called 'Dynamic Rate Switching'. It is this negotiation feature that is responsible for what you are seeing.

Comment: @Silbee thanks, sounds like a answer, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not calculate anything really. The wifi protocol(s) have a feature called 'Dynamic Rate Switching'. It is this negotiation feature that is responsible for what you are seeing. What exactly happens during this negotiation stage depends on many factors, much like Mokubai pointed out in the comments.